# Isolate css of a particular page element in firefox

Tags: css, firefox-addon

Is there a firefox extension or technique that can enable one to isolate all the css of a particular element.I have found one http://code.google.com/p/firefoxcssstealer/ but its not compatible with the newest version of firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised you don't know about [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: I have it installed in firefox but its of no much use for what i am trying to do,i could be wrong :).

Comment: If you use it to inspect an element you should get the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need add-ons for that - it is a built-in feature (since Firefox 10 I think). Click the Firefox button, choose Web Developer and Inspect. Select an element, then click the Style button. It will show you all the styles for that element.